# Why is the result of Byte.parseByte recognised as an integer?

Tags: java, type-conversion

I'm a beginner to Java, I'm fooling around with primitive numerical types, and when I parse String to Byte I can't work with the resulting byte variable (I'm squaring it), as error returned "is type mismatch: cannot convert from int to byte."

```
static byte squareByte(String p1){


       //parse String to byte

        byte result = Byte.parseByte(p1);


       //return type byte

       return result * result;
}
```

I've used  "System.out.println( ((Object)result).getClass().getName());" to determine the variable type after parsing to byte, and it prints that it is byte, so why do I get an error regarding the result being an int?

I find I have to parseByte and then cast Byte just for the multiplication to work, can somebody explain why I have this problem with both Byte and Short, but not with any other primitive numerical type?

Comment: what do you think will will happen when `p1 == 256`?

Comment: As an additional comment on the answers: the JVM (Java Virtual Machine) uses `int` sized instructions for smaller types (short, byte); comparable to common hardware CPUs. Hence there is no overhead in `byte*byte` yielding a byte more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you perform any arithmetic operations (namely `+,-,*,/ or %`) with primitive types that are smaller than `int`, then the values are implicitly converted to an int before the arithmetic is done. This means that the result of `byte * byte` will be `int` rather than `byte` as you would expect.

You can see some further explanations and examples [here](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/170/Syllabus/04/int1e.html)

You can cast the result of the operation back to `byte` to make the code work, although you should think about what you want to happen if the result of the calculation will no longer fit into a `byte` (for example `12` will fit into a byte but `12 * 12` will not)

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `*` operator returns `int`. If you want another type, like `byte`, you will have to do a cast, but there's a risk might overflow the type.

```
return (byte) (result * result);
```

Think of what will happen if the multiplication exceeds the value of `127`, which is the byte limit?

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the JLS specifies that math operations like multiplication / addition etc must return an `int`
You have to use - `return (byte) (result * result);` to explicitly convert the integer result to byte.